# C Program returns garbage value for avg

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

When running this program using pointers and arrays to calculate the grade point average from the user input, it outputs a garbage value. How can I alter the code so that the output is correct?

```
void Insert_Grades(int *array) 
{ 
    int grades[4];
    int i;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        printf("Enter grade %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &grades[i]); 
    } 
    array = grades;
}

void Calculate_Avg(int *array)
{
    int i;
    float avg;
    float sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        sum += *(array + i);
    }
    avg = sum / 4;
    printf( "Grade point average is: %f ", avg);
}

int main() 
{
    int grades[4];
    int i;

    printf("Enter the number of grades:\n");
    Insert_Grades(grades);

    Calculate_Avg(grades); 
    printf("\n"); 
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array` is a local variable of type "pointer to `int`" in `Insert_Grades`. Assigning a value to it is invisible outside of that function, just like for any other local variable.

Comment: Also, code like `array=grades;` doesn't copy values in the array `grades`. In general, it's not possible to assign arrays to arrays or arrays to pointers and have the values automatically copied. In C, you have to manually copy each value one-by-one in a loop.

Comment: Even if `Insert_Grades` would return `grades` it would still be an error since also `grades` is local, and its life-time would end with the function, and any pointer to it would become invalid immediately.

Answer (score 0):

you cant assign arrays.

This operation assigns local pointer `array` with reference of the local array `grades`. For the extral world this operation means nothing.

```
array = grades;
```

You need to copy values instead.

```
memcpy(array, grades, sizeof(grades));
```

or

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < 4; index++)
   array[index] = grades[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problem in your code:

- in function `Insert_Grades`, value are read into the local array `grades`. The last instruction `array = grades` has no effect because it only modifies the argument value, which is just local variable, a pointer to `int` that now points to the first element of `grade` array.

  This explains why the program outputs garbage because the array `grades` defined in the `main()` function is uninitialized and is not modified by `Insert_Grades()`.

  You could copy the array `grade` to the caller array pointed to by `array`, but it seems much simpler to use the `array` pointer to read the values directly where they belong.
- the variable `i` is defined multiple times, with nested scopes.
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Insert_Grades(int *array, int count) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("Enter grade %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } 
}

float Calculate_Avg(const int *array, int count) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum / count;
}

int main() {
    int grades[4];
    int count = sizeof(grades) / sizeof(*grades);
    float avg;

    printf("Enter the grades:\n");
    Insert_Grades(grades, count);

    avg = Calculate_Avg(grades, count); 
    printf("Grade point average is: %.3f\n", avg);
  
    return 0;
}
```